# Zip file can not download in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

My method works fine on localhost but doesn't work in real server. It create zip file data but cann't download.

```
<?php

function downloadBooks($id) {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $id = base64_decode($id);

    $this->loadModel('TeacherRegistrations');
    $data = $this->TeacherRegistrations->findById($id);
    $files = json_decode($data['TeacherRegistrations']['selected_handbook_id'], true);
    $this->Zip->begin("files/test.zip");

    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $folder = $this->Zip->addFile("pdf/$value.pdf", "futurekids/$value.pdf");
    }

    $this->viewClass = 'Media';

    $params = array(
        'id' => 'test.zip',
        'name' => 'futurekids',
        'download' => true,
        'extension' => 'zip',
        'path' => 'files' . DS
    );    
    $this->set($params);    
}

?>
```

Comment: which cakephp version you are using ? Please mention your cakephp version.

Comment: I am using  cakephp 2.6.3

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 2.6 has very simple way to make a file download.
Check:http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files

```
        $file_name = 'test.zip'; // File Name After Download
        $file_path = 'files/test.zip'; // File Path
        if (file_exists(WWW_ROOT . $file_path)) {
            $this->response->file($file_path, array('download' => true, 'name' => $file_name ));

            return $this->response;
        }
```

Also Check http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

first parameter to Zip->add() is file path of the file which exists on system while second parameter is filename you want zip to have.

Comment: You do not have to use 
`$this->viewClass = 'Media';

    $params = array(
        'id' => 'test.zip',
        'name' => 'futurekids',
        'download' => true,
        'extension' => 'zip',
        'path' => 'files' . DS
    );    
    $this->set($params);    `
Instead of that use the code provided and make necessary changes for file name and file path you want to have

Comment: Use `$this->Zip->close();` also to complete zip operation.

Comment: where did you used $this->Zip->close(); ? use it after all addFile operation are complete and after that use the code provided , also check the link attached in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76350/discussion-between-abhishek-and-tarun).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091491/how-to-create-zip-file-and-download-in-cakephp#